# MySQL PIVOT and JOIN inner MAX CASE

Tags: mysql, join, max

I have two tables **domain** and **domain_meta**. What I want to accomplish is to PIVOT table domain_meta (which Im able to do) and join that table with domain. But I cant wrap my head arround how to join this tables with a PIVOT and MAX CASE. Is the simplest way to use some sort of inner select to my domain_meta table? My code looks like this so far:

**domain**

```
SELECT
*
FROM 
domain
ORDER BY id
```

**domain_meta**

```
SELECT
id,
domain_id,
source,
MAX(CASE WHEN (meta_key = 'domain') THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS domain,
MAX(CASE WHEN (meta_key = 'ip') THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS ip,
MAX(CASE WHEN (meta_key = 'link') THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS link,
MAX(CASE WHEN (meta_key = 'net') THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS net
FROM
domain_meta
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id
```

[domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpbfH.jpg)
[domain_meta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mc3lU.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this -

```
SELECT
  d.id,
  d.domain,
  MAX(CASE WHEN (dm.meta_key = 'domain') THEN dm.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS domain,
  MAX(CASE WHEN (dm.meta_key = 'ip') THEN dm.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS ip,
  MAX(CASE WHEN (dm.meta_key = 'link') THEN dm.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS link,
  MAX(CASE WHEN (dm.meta_key = 'net') THEN dm.meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS net
FROM
  domain d
  LEFT JOIN domain_meta dm
    ON d.id = dm.domain_id
GROUP BY d.id
```

Comment: @RogerK Welcome

Comment: You also can automate pivot-query generation, here it is an example - http://codingsight.com/pivot-tables-in-mysql/